# converting url sperators with slash

Tags: php, regex, url

I have a category named like this:

```
$name = 'Construction / Real Estate';
```

Those are two different categories, and I am displaying results from database 
for each of them. But I before that I have to send a user to url just for that category.

Here is the problem, if I did something like this.

```
echo "<a href='site.com/category/{$name}'> $name </a>";
```

The URL will become

```
site.com/cateogry/Construction%20/%20Real%20Estate
```

I am trying to remove the `%20` and make them `/` So, I did `str_replace('%20', '/', $name);` 
But that will become something like this:

```
site.com/cateogry/Construction///Real/Estate
                              ^ ^ and ^ those are the problems.
```

Since it is one word, I want it to appear as `Construction/RealEstate` only.

I could do this by using at-least 10 lines of codes, but I was hoping if there is a regex, and simple php way to fix it.

Comment: Why not make a url-tag in the database, that is unique to every category? Eg.: "construction" and "real-estate".. Than you can use that in the URL and the name as the link label. Especially if dynamic content is created by more admins, that would be preferrable, I would say. That's also a bit more SEO-friendly.. :)

Comment: In addition to the answer by @Tobias Leupold -    $url ="site.com/cateogry/Construction%20/%20Real%20Estate";
echo urldecode($url); // outputs:- site.com/cateogry/Construction / Real Estate

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple solution like this:

```
$s = "site.com/cateogry/Construction%20/%20Real%20Estate";
$s = str_replace('%20', '', $s);

echo $s; // site.com/cateogry/Construction/RealEstate
```

Comment: But still that `Real/Estate` is **one** category. So, it needs to be `RealEstate` only the final result should be `site.com/cateogry/Construction/RealEstate`

Comment: Then it is as simple as replacing `%20` with empty string. See updated answer.

Comment: It probably does not look nice to remove the spaces after they were converted to urlencoded spaces. Besides that, why use a regular expression for something `str_replace` could do faster?

Comment: Yes I agree in the present state `str_replace` will be better. I earlier suggested a regex based solution that's why `preg_replace` was left behind.

Answer (score 1):

You have a string for human consumption, and based on that string you want to create a URL.

To avoid any characters messing up your HTML, or get abuses as XSS attack, you need to escape the human readable string in the context of HTML using `htmlspecialchars()`:

```
$name = 'Construction / Real Estate';
echo "<h1>".htmlspecialchars($name)."</h1>;
```

If that name should go into a URL, it must also be escaped:

```
$url = "site.com/category/".rawurlencode($name);
```

If any URL should go into HTML, it must be escaped for HTML:

```
echo "<a href='".htmlspecialchars($url)."'>";
```

Now the problem with slashes in URLs is that they are most likely not accepted as a regular character even if they are escaped in the URL. And any space character also does not fit into a URL nicely, although they work.

And then there is that black magic of search engine optimization.

For whatever reason, you should convert your category string before you inject it as part of the URL. Do that BEFORE you encode it.

As a general rule, lowercase characters are better, spaces should be dashes instead, and the slash probably should be a dash too:

```
$urlname = strtr(mb_strtolower($name), array(" " => "-", "/" => "-"));
```

And then again:

```
$url = "site.com/category/".rawurlencode($urlname);
echo "<a href='".htmlspecialchars($url)."'>";
```

In fact, using `htmlspecialchars()` is not really enough. The escaping of output that goes into an HTML attribute differs from output as the elements content. If you have a look at the escaper class from Zend Framework 2, you realize that the whole thing of [escaping a HTML attribute value](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Escaper/Escaper.php#L162) is a lot more complicated

No, there is nothing you can do to make it easier. The only chance is to use a function that does everything you need to make things easier for you, but you still need to apply the correct escaping everywhere.

Comment: Hmm, its kind of difficult to understand this. I am fiddling with it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you want to use urldecode() and remove the whitespace afterwards?